# Commutative subspace lattice

Tags: reference-request, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have seen an article in which there is an algebra which was named CSL-algebra (Commutative Subspace Lattice). This algebra is about projection on Banach algebra? I couldn't find any good source to study about it? Do somebody know about it?

Answer (score 4):

This article has useful information about CSL-algebras

**IVAN G. TODOROV**; Subspace Lattices, Reflexivity and Tensor Products, Irish Math. Soc. Bulletin 53 (2004), 57–67